# In flex mxml application on including .as file

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In mxml application made in flex if i place a part of actionscript code in separate file and include it in mail application using (fx:Script source) , then do i have to import all the mx and spark components in .as included file even though they are were already imported in main mxml application ? 
For example if i have mx alert already imported in main mxml file then will i have to import in again in the .as file placed externally although .as file is included in main mxml application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no you don't need to, but you will get compiler warnings if you reference classes inside the include.  These warnings will not prevent you from compiling or deploying your app properly.

If you already had a sample set up for this, why did you ask here instead of just trying it?

Comment: i have tried it but it is not as it should be, so i am confused. If i include an as file , then why i have to import all the stuff again which i have already imported in main application mxml file.

Comment: I'm not understanding.  "What" is not as "what" should be?  I have verified in some of my own code that include files do not need imports.  It will provide a warning; but the code will still compile without errors.